# how to map string to integer in python

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas, I want to map strings to integers, but strangely, the other column covert strings to integers as I wanted, but one column convert strings to floats, and one level doesn't convert correctly and it becomes NaN, the code:

```
data2['post'].map({'集体企业人员':0, '在岗职工':1, '农电工':2})
```

```
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     0.0
3     1.0
4     1.0
5     1.0
6     1.0
7     0.0
8     0.0
9     0.0
10    NaN
11    1.0
12    1.0
13    1.0
14    NaN
15    1.0
16    0.0
17    0.0
18    NaN
19    1.0
20    NaN
21    1.0
22    1.0
23    1.0
24    1.0
25    1.0
26    1.0
27    1.0
28    0.0
```

How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem some values not match keys of `dictionary`, so get `NaN`s.

There are multiple solutions:

1.add missing keys to dict
2.replace `NaN`s by scalar `fillna(100)`

---

3.use `replace` instead `map`, but get mixed values - numeric with strings
3a.replace `NaN`s by original values `fillna(data2['post'])` - same problem as `3.`

---

4.for remove possible trailing whitespace add [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) like `data2['post'].str.strip().map({'集体企业人员':0, '在岗职工':1, '农电工':2})`

Comment: but the level is completely right, no missing keys.

Comment: @littlely Can you check value `data2.loc[10, 'post']` ? There is no whitespace?

Comment: @littlely - There has to be some data problem, is possible share your data? If possible some trailing whitespaces, try `data2['post'].str.strip().map({'集体企业人员':0, '在岗职工':1, '农电工':2})`

Comment: yes, there is a whitespace in the string of '农电工 ', thanks!